# Linksys WRT54GL Reset to factory firmware?

Tags: firmware

I just purchased a WRT54GL that I want to flash with dd-wrt.  On the dd-wrt wiki I read that I should first upgrade the linksys firmware to v.4.21.1 so I did so, but now the web gui is messed up.  I can log in, but nothing is legible.  I have used IE, FF and Chrome, but all emit the same behavior.  Is there any way i can do a command line flash to get my gui back?

Edit: Looks like I have flashed my router with the wrong version of firmware - not sure how I boneheaded that, but I sure did...

Comment: This should be on SuperUser, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Have you already defaulted the router?  Press and hold the reset button on the back of the router for 30 seconds. This will clear your NVRAM, the configuration and reset the password to admin.

Comment: yes, and I tried pressing, holding for 30 seconds, then powering off, holding for 30 seconds, powering back on and holding for 30 more seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the device into [Management Mode](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Recover_from_a_Bad_Flash) and sending it the correct firmware (either the proper Linksys firmware, or the full DD-WRT) via TFTP, as described on the aforelinked page.  This way, you can avoid having to fumble through the messed-up management GUI in an attempt to use the firmware upgrade web form.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a problem flashing an official router firmware for my Linksys AM300 modem. Turned out that I had been using a wrong power supply for the device, which did not have enough juice to perform a correct flash.